# How to overcome missing of "sp::Point" to create points layer in shapefile?

Tags: r, polygon, point, sp

I can produce Polygon layer from matrix in following way:

```
pols <- lapply(cdf, Polygon)
    pls <- lapply(seq_along(pols), function(i) Polygons(list(pols[[i]]), ID = i))
    sps <- SpatialPolygons(pls)
    sps_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sps, data.frame(x = rep(NA, length(pls)), row.names = names(pls)))
```

while `cdf` is a matrix of points (x, y) for the polygon(s). My question is: how to do the same for points or even circles? I don't have a function to cast like `pols <- lapply(cdf, Point)` to produce `SpatialPoints` object from many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the help for `SpatialPoints`, specifically the arguments:

```
Arguments:

  coords: numeric matrix or data.frame with coordinates (each row is a
          point); in case of SpatialPointsDataFrame an object of class
          SpatialPoints-class is also allowed
```

So a simple two-column matrix (here with four rows) can be a set of four points:

```
> SpatialPoints(cbind(runif(4),runif(4)))
SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,] 0.9010205 0.5651983
[2,] 0.4403097 0.3789879
[3,] 0.3639780 0.1379548
[4,] 0.1035837 0.9666854
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA 
>
```

Add coordinate system as needed via `proj4string=` as per the documentation.

Points are simpler than polygons (which can be made of multiple rings and islands and so on) so the constructor is simpler, and there's no `Point` class like there is `Polygon` for `SpatialPolygons`.

Comment: Yes, maybe too easy for a class handler.